# Полу прозрачные стены после импорта в юнити, как исправить?

Tags: unity3d

почему в юнити после импорта модели у стен какие-то проблемы начинают происходить. Импортирую в FBX формате
[image: блендер]

[image: Unity]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что полигоны смотрят в другую сторону.

[image: FaceOrientation]

- Ставим флаг `Face Orientation`.
- Выделяешь `Face`
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> / `Flip`

А вообще для таких вопросов есть [Blender Stack Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/).